# How plugins_loaded works?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am developing a plugin for woocommerce payment gateway.

When I put the code of class definition inside the callback function who is fired by 'plugins_loaded',it works.

```
<?php
    add_action('plugins_loaded','WC_test_gateway_plugin');
    function WC_test_gateway_plugin{
        class my_gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateways{
            //code
        }
    }
?>
```

But when I put it into global scope, it will show that the WC_Payment_Gateways is undefined.

```
<?php
    class my_gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateways{
        //code
    }
?>
```

What's the difference between these 2 practices?

Is it a bad practice to put class definition inside callback function?
Any better way for it?

Comment: [`plugins_loaded`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_loaded/) is meant to be used here, and you should make a file for `my_gateway` class and `include` it in your `WC_test_gateway_plugin` callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your class definition in a separate file, say in `/your-plugin-dir/classes/my-gateway.php` like usual:

```
    <?php
        class my_gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateways {
            //code
        }
    ?>
```

Then use this CODE to include the file on `plugins_loaded` action from your main plugin file:

```
    add_action('plugins_loaded', 'WC_test_gateway_plugin');
    function WC_test_gateway_plugin() {
        require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'classes/my-gateway.php';
        // instantiate your class here or in your class file or anywhere after this function is called.
    }
```

Now you'll get access to `WC_Payment_Gateways` because by now `WC_Payment_Gateways` is defined, since WordPress fires `plugin_loaded` action hook only after all the plugins have loaded their main files.

Comment: missing brackets for WC_test_gateway_plugin function

Comment: @HarkályGergő thanks, updated.